# Выдает ошибку в pug при попытке написать dropdown menu

Tags: html, pug

Необходимо написать код на pug, который создает кнопку с вываливающимся меню при нажатии. Что здесь не так? В консоли выдает ошибку.

```
hr
                .dropdown
                    button.dropbtn Dropdown
                    .dropdown-content
                        a(href='#') Link 1
                        a(href='#') Link 2
                        a(href='#') Link 3
hr
```

И консоль: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  ERROR in Module build failed (from ../node_modules/pug-html-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\copysoe\storyofeqs\src\ts\components\app\character\character.pug:142:1
    140|                                                                            a.dropdown-item(*ngFor="let a of animations; let i = index" (click)="setActiveAnimation(i)")
    141|                                                                                    | {{a().name}}
  > 142|                    hr
---------^
    143|                                    .dropdown
    144|                         button.dropbtn Dropdown
    145|                         .dropdown-content

Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both
```

Comment: Приведите ошибку в текстовом виде

Comment: Готово. Предоставил в текстовом варианте ошибку из терминала.

Comment: _Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both_ - ошибка явно говорит - используй либо только пробелы либо только табы но не смешивая